# set select option 'selected' in a modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select field and I have to select one of those options with jQuery. I have this method, and it works for me anywhere, except in a modal.
When I open my target page, it opens a modal automatically with a select field which I am trying to set his selected item.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='modal small fade' id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="UpdateMPrev" >
                <select id="echelle"  name="echelle" class="form-control">                     
                    <option value="mensuelle"> Mensuelle</option>  
                    <option value="trimestrielle">Trimestrielle</option> 
                    <option value="semestrielle" > Semestrielle</option> 
                    <option value="annuelle" > Annuelle</option> 
                    <option value="aucun"> Aucun</option> 
                </select>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then directly I have this script:

```
<script>
    var echelle= document.getElementById('echelle');
    echelle.value = 'trimestrielle';
</script>
```

The same code, at the same page works, only if I put the select field in the main page, I mean not in the modal, can any one help?

Comment: Are you reusing the `ID`s?

Comment: and when does this script run? After the modal is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should place your script before the html code of the modal as below.

```
<script>
    var echelle= document.getElementById('echelle');
    echelle.value = 'trimestrielle';
</script>

<div class='modal small fade' id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="UpdateMPrev" >
                <select id="echelle"  name="echelle" class="form-control">                     
                    <option value="mensuelle"> Mensuelle</option>  
                    <option value="trimestrielle">Trimestrielle</option> 
                    <option value="semestrielle" > Semestrielle</option> 
                    <option value="annuelle" > Annuelle</option> 
                    <option value="aucun"> Aucun</option> 
                </select>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```