# Select option not working for Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, modal-dialog

Can someone help clarify here? I am trying to do the same thing as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596594/set-select-option-selected-in-a-modal-bootstrap/42446394#42446394) but set the value dynamically. However when I do this, even though I'm setting the values before opening the modal, the value does not seem to be getting set.

I have a Create New Campaign button as part of a table which when clicked, calls the javascript methods shown below:

```
<th data-field="create_campaign"><span class="create_campaign" text="{{product.id}}"><a class="" href="#" data-target="campaign_modal" value="{{product.id}}">create new campaign</a></span><br></th>
```

HTML

```
<div id="campaign_modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <blockquote>
            Product Campaign
        </blockquote>
        <div id="" class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5">
                <select id="product_selector" name="product_selector">
                    <option disable value=" ">Select a Product </option>
                    {% for product in all_org_products %}
                        <option value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5">
                <input type="text" id="campaign" class=""/>
                <label for="campaign" id="label_campaign"> Campaign </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s2">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light teal" onclick="submitCampaign()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" center">
            <span class="done_btn"><button id="done_btn" class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light modal-action"><i class="material-icons left" >done</i>Done</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('.create_campaign').click(function () {
        product_id = $(this).attr('text');
        var product_select = document.getElementById('product_selector');
        console.log(product_select);
        var index=0;
        for (var i=0; i<product_select.options.length; i++){
            if (product_select.options[i].value == product_id){
                index=i;
                product_select.value=product_id
                break;
            }
        }
        product_select.selectedIndex = index;
        openCampaignModal();
    });

    function openCampaignModal(){
        $('#campaign_modal').openModal();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the code was under the $(document).ready(function()) which is why it was not able to get the value at that time. I took my functions outside the document.ready method and its working now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your javascript is running without error and it is above your modal. Your modal is getting compiled before your javascript runs and so that data cannot be fetched when you click on modal.

Comment: The javascript runs without errors but how can I ensure that it is run above the modal? Currently, as the option (create new campaign) is clicked, I first set the value of the select element and only then call openModal.

Comment: Add script next to <body> tag or include your script.js file in <head>

Comment: I'm using materializecss so I don't have any <body> tag. Also, not sure how I can know the value of the select before hand because there are multiple options to 'create new campaign' and depending on the one that was clicked, I would like the select dropdown to be preselected with that value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an not familiar with `Django` templates, but your markup suggests perhaps the template is not being rendered until openModal() is called. Is this the case?

If so, then you would need to run your auto-select code after the modal's `<option>` elements have been rendered.

To test this you could put a console.log inside your for loop, to check which options are available when the click event happens.

```
for (var i=0; i<product_select.options.length; i++){    
    console.log(product_select.options[i])
}
```

Comment: All the options are available before openModal is called. Even if I don't call it at all, all options are already there.

Comment: @RajveerParikh Have you tested that your code is finding the value and successfully setting the selectedIndex?

Comment: So I had tested that it was getting the correct value. But it was not setting the selectIndex, which was the problem. I have figured it out though. I realized that it was all under $(document).ready, which is why it was not being set on the click. Fixed now, Thank you!